# PC starts but Windows doesn't, have to go to bios and select boot drive each time, how to fix?

Tags: windows-7, boot, bios, dell-xps

I was installing windows 10 using a usb on a windows 7 device. It said there were no upgrades found during installation and said to take out usb and it should restart so I did that. Once the PC restarted I waited for windows 7 to reload but all I saw was a black screen with _ flashing at the top left. Every time I restart or shut it down I have to select the boot drive before going into windows. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Boot into Windows using whatever complicated method you currently have. Go into Command Prompt as an Administrator*** and run this command:
`bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path EFI\Microsoft\boot\bootmgfw.efi`
This reroutes the bootloader to run the Microsoft EFI bootloader and run it to boot into your specified Windows version.
**Does this not work?**
Find a way to boot into WinRE on Windows 10. Typically, this is done by clicking Restart in the Lock Screen while holding Shift. To get into the Lock Screen press Windows Key-L. Select "More troubleshooting options" until you find Command Prompt. Run these commands:
`bcdboot /fixboot`
`bcdboot /fixmbr`
`bcdboot /rebuildbcd`
These repair the boot process and MBR partitions.
***To do this, press Windows Key-R, type `cmd`, and click Run while holding Ctrl-Shift.